# Retrieve final URL phonegap download

Tags: javascript, url, cordova, download

I'm implementing offline caching of HTML page with minimal support like picture and css.

I use phonegap API to retrive the file and then parse it. I'm retrieving the CSS and pictures link, building the request with BuildUrlCss function (handling root, relative and absolute URLs):

```
 fileTransfer.download(
   uri,
   Path,
   function(entry) {
      alert("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);

      entry.file(function(file){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
             // Retrieve CSS file linked in article
             var cssRegExp = /<link.*?href=(?:"|)(.*\.css).*?>/g;
             while (cssFile = cssRegExp.exec(evt.target.result)) {
                  alert(BuildUrlCss(cssFile[1], Url));
              }
            reader.readAsText(file);
      });
   },
   function(error) {
      alert("download error source " + error.source);
      alert("download error target " + error.target);
   }
 )
```

This is working fine as soon as there is no http redirection in the passing Url.

I would like to know if there is any way to retrieve the "final" Url used by phonegap API (as phonegap API support http redirection and download the pointed Url) in the success function for example or using any other javascript function or library?

Thanks a lot for your help.
This issue is driving me crazy ...

Regards.

Florent

#

Here is an update, I have tried a wget and also check my url in Firebug and noticed that wget/browser received a 302 response, giving the final URL.

This is the final url I would like to get in javascript.